# Prevent object rewrite when serializing and unserializing

Tags: php, serialization

I'm noticing that I'm losing array content when serializing a simple object and I assume that I'm rewriting the array somehow. How to structure the code properly allowing data preservation from originally initiated object?

```
<?php

class MyClass {

    private $array;

    function __construct($array) {
        $this->array = $array;
    }

    public function __sleep() {
        return $this->array;
    }
}

$array = array(
    'i1' => 1,
    'i2' => 2,
    'i3' => 3,
    'i4' => 4
);

$obj = new MyClass($array);
$ser = serialize($obj);
$des = unserialize($ser);

print_r($obj);
echo '<br><br>';
print_r($ser);
echo '<br><br>';
print_r($des);
?>
```

Output:

```
MyClass Object ( [array:MyClass:private] => Array ( [i1] => 1 [i2] => 2 [i3] => 3 [i4] => 4 ) )

O:7:"MyClass":4:{s:1:"1";N;s:1:"2";R:2;s:1:"3";R:2;s:1:"4";R:2;}

MyClass Object ( [array:MyClass:private] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => )
```

Comment: Try Implementing `Serializable` interface to `MyClass`.

Comment: The question looks like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161065/object-serialization-sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation for magic `__sleep()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.magic-functions.php) we can find an explanation how it should be used

> That function is being run prior to any serialization. It can clean up
>   the object and is supposed to **return an array with the names** of all
>   variables of that object that should be serialized.

Instead of returning just private variable in `__sleep`, I must return it's name.

```
<?php

class MyClass {

    private $array;
    private $test;

    function __construct($array, $test) {
        $this->array = $array;
        $this->test = $test;
    }

    public function __sleep() {        
        return array('array', 'test');
    }
}

$test = 'test';
$array = array(
    'i1' => 1,
    'i2' => 2,
    'i3' => 3,
    'i4' => 4
);

$obj = new MyClass($array, $test);
$ser = serialize($obj);
$des = unserialize($ser);

print_r($obj);
echo '<br><br>';
print_r($ser);
echo '<br><br>';
print_r($des);
```

Result:

```
MyClass Object ( [array:MyClass:private] => Array ( [i1] => 1 [i2] => 2 [i3] => 3 [i4] => 4 ) [test:MyClass:private] => test )

O:7:"MyClass":2:{s:14:"MyClassarray";a:4:{s:2:"i1";i:1;s:2:"i2";i:2;s:2:"i3";i:3;s:2:"i4";i:4;}s:13:"MyClasstest";s:4:"test";}

MyClass Object ( [array:MyClass:private] => Array ( [i1] => 1 [i2] => 2 [i3] => 3 [i4] => 4 ) [test:MyClass:private] => test )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Implementing `Serializable` interface to `MyClass`.

```
class MyClass implements Serializable {

    private $array;

    function __construct($array) {
       $this->array = $array;
    }

    public function serialize() {
        return serialize($this->array);
    }

    public function unserialize($array) {
        $this->data = unserialize($array);
    }

    public function __sleep() {
        return $this->array;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you.

Comment: I've read up on examples and I don't think I need magical function `__sleep` when implementing `Serializable`. http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php

Comment: Yes, just ignore it. if it helps, you can accept the answer.

Comment: Thank  you, I'll consider it. I'm looking for an answer that more closely reflecting the example, if possible. I'll let the question remain open until I'm sure there's no closer solution.